# ghostscript ps pdfmark command /BDC for content tagging (PDF/UA and WCAG 2.0)

Tags: accessibility, ghostscript

I have a pdf with PDF/UA and WCAG 2.0 compliance generated using ghostscript from a postscript file.
Accessibility features are implemented using the /BDC pdfmark command.

The pdf is correctly managed by NVDA screen reader when opened with Acrobar Reader but if it is opened from Firefox, Accessibility is lost (no access to Headings, Tables and List).

The problem seems to be how ghostscript treats the dictionary associated to the tag.

Is there a way to tell ghostscript to keep the dictionary inline and not as reference to a page resource?

Thanks

Example:

**postscript**:

[ /H1 << /MCID 0 >> /BDC pdfmark
(Heading 1) 7747 2920 mvs
[ /EMC pdfmark

**actual pdf** generated by ghostscript 10 (only tag and text operand for clarity):

/H1 /Rnn BDC
(Heading 1) Tj
EMC

where /Rnn is a reference to the page Resources -> Properties dictionary containing the tag H1 dictionary   <</MCID 0>>

**needed pdf**:

/H1 <</MCID 0>> BDC
(Heading 1) Tj
EMC

Comment: No, there is no way to tell the pdfwrite device (not Ghostscript, the Ghostscript PDF output device) **how** to write marked content. Is the PDF output invalid ? If so raise a bug report with Ghostscript (bugs.ghostscript.com). If not, raise a bug report with the PDF consumer (Firefox ?) that they aren't handling valid content properly. Sounds to me like a problem with Firefox though.

Comment: In general, don't take into account PDF readers integrated in browsers. They are bad and don't interpret accessibility tags well, if at all, anyway. If the structure is correctly rendered in Adobe Reader and with Jaws or NVDA, you can consider it fine.